# Discovering SQL Server instances .Net 4.6

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net, .net-4.6

I am trying to discover all the sql-server instances in a network from a new client but am running into a problem.

First of all this is the code that I'm using (but all other ways of discovering instances seem to have the same problem):

```
Dim instance = System.Data.Sql.SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance
For Each r In instance.GetDataSources().Rows
    // Do something with the instances returned
Next
```

What has me stumped is:
- This only occurs when the .Net framework 4.6 is installed.
- This code works fine when the application is targeting .Net framework 3.5 or older but returns an empty table when running against .Net framework 4.0 (even if .net framework 4.6 is installed !).

Obviously requiring clients not to install 4.6 is not an option, neither is targetting an older framework. Are there any workaround to this problem. Even more interesting, what's the origin of this issue in the new version of .Net?

Comment: The note on this piece of documentation seems to imply this isn't a very reliable method call: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.data.sql.sqldatasourceenumerator.getdatasources(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

This problem is caused by .Net Framework 4.6

I have faced the same problem. Even when i set target framework to 4.5 or 4.5.2 to be more specific still it does not work.

How ever when I uninstalled 4.6 my code started to work again.

Answer (score 0):

There is definitely a problem with .NET Framework 4.6 - it's been logged multiple times: https://goo.gl/QAeM9A